# How do I use group by on one column which is having many entries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I want to use group by on one column which is having many entries

table_a

```
Name price
AAA  12
BBB  13
AAA  0
CCC  24
AAA  0
DDD  0
```

Now I want to find out `Name` which is having `Price` as `0`

but as I'm having entries `AAA` 3 times I can't directly write simple sql with condition 
`NOT Equal to 0`

Please help me I want to print result for above table_a should be

only `D` as it is having `0` as `price`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive this by using aggregate functions `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause as:

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63d97/1)

```
SELECT name,SUM(price) as price
FROM table 
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(price) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! @OP: If you have negative values for price then use `MAX` instead of `SUM`

Comment: but what will happen if AAA is having its first value is 5 and next as -5...its sum will be zero

Answer (score 3):

I assumed price cannot be lower than zero:

```
SELECT Name
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Name
HAVING SUM(price) = 0
```

Or with additional condition of only one price, which is zero

```
SELECT Name
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND SUM(price) = 0
```

Comment: I believe this is the right answer as the OP said only `D` as it has a prize of zero. So the OP only needs those with zero price and only have one entry. Unless otherwise of course.

Comment: only second query is perfect (thats what i think)

Answer (score 1):

```
select name,max(price) as price from table group by name having max(price) =0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select name,max(price)
group by name
having max(price)=0
```